# What is going wrong with this API?

Tags: php, pdo

I am coding a website for my friend whom plays Habbo Hotel which is a virtual game. He linked me to some API.
http://habboemotion.com/guide/habinfo & http://habboemotion.com/guide/habboapi

I have been using this code to show the data from the api.

```
<?php

  $info = habbo( "Tyler", "com" );
  if( $info ) {
    foreach( $info->user AS $name ) {
      echo $name->motto;
    }
  } else {
    echo "Habbo not found";
  }

?>
```

Why is nothing appearing? It just appears to be a blank screen.

Comment: Did you actually define the `habbo()` function in a file and `include/require` it as in the linked example?  Always when developing and testing PHP code, enable error display. A blank screen when output is expected usually indicates there was a fatal error in your code.  At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous person said, make sure to include your habbo() function.

I changed the habbo() function to remove gzip compression and gzinflate(). That seemed to fix the blank page issue. However it seems to take a few seconds to load the page and is on the slow side.

It would also appear that $user->motto isn't allowed. As such, I've replaced it with $friends->motto.

Hope this helps! I am still very new to APIs.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); // Debugging
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // Debugging

function habbo( $name, $hotel ) {

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.habbo." . $hotel .     "/api/public/users" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Accept-Encoding: identity' ) ); // Changed to "identity"
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );

$response = curl_exec( $ch ); // Added
//$get = gzinflate( substr( curl_exec( $ch ), 10, -8 ) );
//preg_match( "/setCookie\((.*)\);/", $get, $get );
//$get = explode( ",", str_replace( array( "'", " " ), "", $get[1] ) );

//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( "Cookie:" . $get[0] . "=" .     $get[1] ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.habbo." . $hotel .  "/api/public/users?name=" . $name );

$id = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ) );

if( isset( $id ) && $id->profileVisible == 1 ) {

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.habbo." . $hotel . "/api/public/users/" . $id->uniqueId . "/profile" );
  $info = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ) );

} else 
  $info = false;

curl_close( $ch );

return $info;

}
```

Here is the function call:

```
$info = habbo( "Tyler", "com" );
if( $info ) {
    foreach( $info->friends AS $friend ) {
    echo $friend->motto . "<br />";
}
} else {
echo "habbo not found or homepage hidden";
}

?>
```